# Where can I see the difference in those mounts?

Tags: devices, disk, xfs, device-mapper

```
# mount | grep 'rootvg-var\b'
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var on /var type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var on /var/lib/docker/containers type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var on /var/lib/docker/overlay2 type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

The same device on the left `/dev/mapper/rootvg-var` is mounted to different paths on the right. If I look at each of the three I see different directories inside, so it's not mounting the same thing at three different places.

How can I found out what is the difference between those three? How does this work?

```
# lvdisplay /dev/mapper/rootvg-var
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/rootvg/var
  LV Name                var
  VG Name                rootvg
  LV UUID                zIM6j1-lcGB-qNd1-NUPn-vZTh-8FOv-EwL40U
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2019-07-08 15:18:13 +1200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                6.00 GiB
  Current LE             1536
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:2
```

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 (Maipo)